# Qt show() function after hide(), worked when the window inactive but not active

Tags: qt

I have made a simple qt program that grabs a picture and display it using QPainter/QPaintEvent widget. I make it on QPainter so that I can put a X mark on the picture from a user input. I have made the program window to hide and show based on an external button input. It works well if I set the running program window inactive. But if I set the window to active and triggered the show/hide function, it crashes with error:
`Fatal IO error: client killed`

Also, when I tried to use show() function after hide(), it gives 2-3 of a same error (applies when the window either active and inactive):
`QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread`

Is this a bug in qt? Any suggestion on workaround this problem?

Comment: Are you using threads? If so, are you trying to manipulate the Gui while in those threads?

Comment: We would need more information to say for certain... but a big old hint is the warning message.  You appear to be trying to do things inside an object owned by one thread while a different thread is active.  Usually, this involves trying to directly fiddle with the UI from a different thread.